# .net core Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload a picture, send the picture by the front end (axios request), and then this error is returned by the server.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' because the type requires a JSON
> object to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the
> JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
> deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
> interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
> deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
> to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path 'file',
> line 1, position 339."

```
    [HttpPost("add")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Post post, IFormFile file){............}
```

this is my axios request

```
  const submit = useCallback(
    async (values: PostExtensions) => {
      debugger;
      setLoading(true);

      const tarih = dayjs(values.date);
      values.tarih = dayjs(date, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z").format();

      const formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("postId", values.postId!);
      formdata.append("file", values.file![0]);
      formdata.append("userId", values.userId!);
      formdata.append("projectId", values.projectId!);
      formdata.append("date", values.date!);

      await entitySubmit({
        values: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values)),
        dispatch: dispatch,
        returndata: true,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        links: [
          {
            type: 0,
            link: "post/addpost",
            actionType: ActionType.add_Post,
            method: "POST",
          },
          {
            type: 1,
            link: "post/editpost",
            actionType: ActionType.edit_Post,
            method: "POST",
          },
        ],
        id: "postId",
      });
      return null;
    },
    [show, dispatch]
  );
```

when I tried to post formdata, It does'nt submit.

**EDIT 1**: I found the problem where is,
formData send null file object something like this

```
formdata.get('file') // '[Object object]'
```

Comment: first try to hit that api from postman or any api tester software then move for consuming that api in frontend language.

Comment: How can I test posting image file on postman or whatever ?

Comment: Can you show the axios code that is uploading the file? From the error, I would guess you are trying to post it as JSON and it should be posted as a multi-part upload

Comment: When I tried content type of multi-part form data, I got this error "Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."

Comment: test in postman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093843/iformfile-in-net-core-web-api-is-null-for-axios-and-ajax-file-upload-but-works

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I've found that sending files via ajax is often times much easier when using base64 encoding. Here's a small sample of how you can achieve this:

```
//client side
//this function converts a file object to a base64 string
const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
   reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

document.getElementById("upload").onclick = async () => {
    const file = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0];
    const base64 = await toBase64(file);
    const response = await fetch('/home/upload', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( {base64 /*add any additional values you need here */})
})
    const json = await response.json();
}

//server side
public class UploadData
{
    public string Base64Data { get; set; }
    //any additional properties you need here....
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload([FromBody]UploadData data)
{
    var base64 = data.Base64Data.Substring(data.Base64Data.IndexOf(",") + 1); //bit of a hack, need to remove the additional part of the base64 string that JS generates but that .net doesn't like
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    //bytes is now available to do whatever you need with
    return Json(someObjectYouWantToReturn);
}
```

Hopefully this code will be a good enough starting point to get you where you need. Again, base64 might not be what you're after, but I use this approach a lot, I find it simple to deal with personally.